# What is the meaning of the control-sequence \@undefined in the pgf/tikz source-code?

Tags: tikz-pgf, sourcecode

The control-sequence `\@undefined` appears several times in the pgf/tikz source-code. For instance, in the file `<pgf/tikz install dir>/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex` it appears twice:

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax%
\else%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\@undefined%
    \else\pgfkeys@csname@testtrue%
    \fi%
\fi
```

and

```
\ifx\foreach\@undefined
```

but it appears in other files as well.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find where `\@undefined` is defined in the pgf/tikz source-code. It is possible that I didn't search properly, because the letters `\` and `@` are tricky.

- What does `\@undefined` mean in the context of the pgf/tikz source-code?
- Is it defined anywhere in the pgf/tikz source-code, or is it a known TeX control-sequence (or some extension of TeX, e.g. e-TeX) that I'm simply not familiar with?

I've considered the possibility that `\@undefined` is simply some control-sequence that is assumed to be undefined, and its purpose is to help test whether other control-sequences are defined using the idiom

```
\ifx\someControlSequence\@undefined ...
```

However, if this is indeed the intended use, then I don't understand the first example above, since the expression

```
 \expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\@undefined
```

will always evaluate to `false`: this is obvious if the control-sequence `\csname#1\endcsname` is defined, and if it isn't defined, then the `\csname...\endcsname` construct will define it to be `\relax` (this is just how the `\csname...\endcsname` construct works -- see exercise 7.7 on p. 40 of the TeXbook, 20th printing 1991).

Comment: Well, afaik, the expansion shall construct the csname, so that `\ifx` does not check `\csname` to be something.

Comment: @TeXnician: Sorry, I didn't get it. Could you please explain another way?

Comment: I'm not really sure about it, but from my understanding: The `\expandafter` causes `\csname` to construct a control sequence name, which will be checked against the `\@undefined` by `\ifx`.

Comment: @TeXnician: This makes sense. But it doesn't explain what `\@undefined` means, which is what I'd like to know.

Comment: That was not my aim, just to question your last paragraph.

Comment: And another annotation: `\@undefined` is not defined by PGF. You can look into the LaTeX kernel and find it's used.

Comment: @TeXnician: I don't understand, you think that my last paragraph is false? In other words, you think that even if `\@undefined` is an undefined control-sequence, the conditional `\expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\@undefined ...` can sometimes evaluate to `true`?

Comment: @TeXnician: How can I look into the LaTeX kernel? Where are the sources?

Comment: `\@undefined` is not defined, that is its purpose.

Comment: @EvanAad the test will always evaluate to false, so it's dead code. It happens...

Comment: Unless `#1` is the literal text `@undefined`, and then `\expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\@undefined` evaluates to true and also leaves `\@undefined` as `\relax`

Comment: @MarkWibrow: Do you think this is the intended behavior, or is this a bug?

Comment: @MarkWibrow true although that is effectively just defining `\@undefined` before the test, `\let\@undefined...` and that would break so much code it's best not to consider it:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\@undefined` is a csname that by convention is never defined. It would be a bad idea to break that convention as several core latex commands (including for example `\caption`) include tests such as the ones you show, that assume that it is not defined.

So

```
\ifx\foreach\@undefined
```

tests if `\foreach` has been defined

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\@undefined%
\else\pgfkeys@csname@testtrue%
\fi%
```

is actually just the same as

```
\pgfkeys@csname@testtrue
```

as the result of expanding `\csname#1\endcsname` is never undefined.

Comment: Thank you. What about `\undefined`? Since in the same file where I took the examples that I quoted in my original post, `\undefined` is used as well as `\@undefined`. Is `\undefined` also a control-sequence that is by convention undefined?

Comment: @EvanAad `\undefined` is in the TeX Book.

Comment: @cfr: Are `\undefined` and `\@undefined` interchangeable? If they are, why are they both used in the same file?

Comment: @EvanAad you can use `\EvanAad` or `\Zzzzzzz` they are all the same, any undefined command would work the same way. plain tex uses `\undefined` but latex uses `\@undefined` as it is less likely to get defined by a casual user, and because of its convention of using `@` named commands for internal uses.